# com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer GET reading data problem

Tags: url, attributes, httpserver

I'm using Http servet implements com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer. on my client midlet I'm using the following url:
    String url = "http://localhost:22334/name=" + name;
When request arrived to server, the recieved HttpExchange does not contins the "name=john" data?
How can i read the data from the url?
Thanks,
Eyal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use

```
String url = "http://localhost:22334?name=" + name;
```

instead of yours with the slash: http://localhost:22334/name

Comment: you are trying to use a request parameter named name. Is that right?

Comment: Still requestBody is empty after using String url = "http://localhost:22334?name=" + name;

Comment: How do i use request parameter? and im trying the foollowing also:  String name = (String) exchange.getAttribute("name");    and    String name2 = (String) exchange.getHttpContext().getAttributes().get("name"); and still get null.

Comment: Assuming that exchange is a HttpServletRequest object then you will get the parameter value with the  getParameter method: exchange.getParameter("name") . NOT getAttribute, but getParameter.

Comment: I'm using com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpExchange. I'm not using HttpServletRequest

Comment: On the server i'm using: server.createContext("/", new BbHandler()); BbHandler is my implementation for com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpHandler.

Comment: Solved by using ServerSocket.